# MongoDB not properly 2DIndex-ing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I have a dataset of ~400k objects in the format:

```
{
    "trip": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -73.9615,
                    40.6823
                ],
                [
                    -73.9704,
                    40.7849
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
           ......
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making a `2dsphere` index on mLab like so:

```
{"trip.geometry" : "2dsphere"}
```

Which I assume just calls:

```
db.collection.createIndex( {"trip.geometry" : "2dsphere"} )
```

When I try to do a `$geoWithin` query like so (about 500 hits):

```
db.collection.find(
   {
     "trip.geometry": {
       $geoWithin: {
          $geometry: {
             type : "Polygon" ,
             coordinates: [
                            [
                              [-74.0345,40.7267],
                              [-73.9824,40.7174],
                              [-73.9934,40.7105],
                              [-74.0345,40.7267]
                            ]
                          ]
          }
       }
   }}
)
```

I noticed it was very slow, ~2 seconds. I then tried deleting the index entirely, and the time increase was very slight. ~0.5 seconds. Is it possible that this query is not using the index the I had set? I've [included the explain() here](http://pastebin.com/zg1ydMhW).

By my interpretation, the winning plan first fetches all the data based on a simple filter, then uses the `2dindex`. Shouldn't it start out using the `2dindex`, given that the `lat` and `lon` data aren't indexed directly?